# MYSQL - Self Join with Junction Table

Tags: mysql

Having trouble with doing a self-join on a homework assignment. The self-join is also pulling from a junction table rec_artist. Here is the code I'm running, and returning an empty set. Why do I return an empty set?

```
SELECT 
    a1.name, 
    a2.name, 
    ra.rec_id
FROM 
    artists a1, artists a2, rec_artist ra1, rec_artist ra2, rec_artist ra
WHERE 
    ra1.rec_id = ra2.rec_id
AND
    ra1.artist_id = a1.id
AND
    ra2.artist_id = a2.id
AND
    ra1.artist_id > ra2.artist_id;
```

Table Schema:

```
recordings
rec_title (varchar)
rec_id (Primary Key)
sales (dec)
genre_id (Foreign Key)

genres
id (primary key)
name (varchar)

artists
id (primary key)
name (varchar)

rec_artist (junction table)
artist_id (primary key) 
rec_id (primary key)
```

The question is:

List pairs of artists that have at least one recording in common.

 Your result set must have 3 columns: both artists' names and the recording_id they have in
common (use only one SQL statement).

 Only unique pairs should be displayed.

 Do not pair an artist with himself/herself.

Comment: Drop the old ansi comma join syntax which is over 25 years old and learn proper `JOIN` syntax..  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html ,.. That makes the query alot eazier the read and understand besides no mistakes into running a cartesian product when you didn't define the correct where statement..

Comment: Okay, I understand that the JOIN syntax makes things clearer and safer. Our teacher has been showing us the comma method so it is hard to break out of as all our examples are done this way.

Comment: "Our teacher has been showing us the comma method so it is hard to break out of as all our examples are done this way." Show the teacher the better way and teach the teacher

Comment: Get rid of `rec_artist ra`.

Comment: This query should not return an empty result. It should list all the pairs of artists that have a recording in common, and create a cross product with ALL `rec_artist.rec_id` values.

Comment: When I try this, getting rid of 'rec_artist ra' , I get an error that there is an unknown column in the field list 'ra.rec_id' . Even when calling it 'rec_artist.rec_id'.

Comment: It should be `ra1.rec_id` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Still empty set... not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: i also posted a other method which works **only** on MySQL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should not return an empty result. It should actually return a huge result. You're correctly finding the pairs of artists that have recordings in common, but each pair will then be duplicated with *every* `rec_id` in the `rec_artists` table, because you have no conditions on the `rec_artists ra` table in the `WHERE` clause.

You don't need a third join with `rec_artists`. You can simply select the `rec_id` column from either of the `rec_artists` tables in the self-join; it doesn't matter which you use, since `ra1.rec_id = ra2.rec_id`.

The correct query is:

```
SELECT a1.name, a2.name, ra1.rec_id
FROM artists a1, artists a2, rec_artist ra1, rec_artist ra2
WHERE ra1.rec_id = ra2.rec_id
AND ra1.artist_id = a1.id
AND ra2.artist_id = a2.id
AND ra1.artist_id > ra2.artist_id;
```

Or using ANSI JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT a1.name, a2.name, ra1.rec_id
FROM rec_artist AS ra1
JOIN rec_artist AS ra2 ON ra1.rec_id = ra2.rec_id AND ra1.artist_id > ra2.artist_id
JOIN artists AS a1 ON ra1.artist_id = a1.id
JOIN artists AS a2 ON ra2.artist_id = a2.id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/745d88/2)

Comment: Really appreciate your help! I am still returning an empty set with both of these queries.

Comment: Then you must not have any artists who share a recording. I've added a demo showing that it works.

Comment: That may be the case... it shouldn't be, but I see that it works correctly in your demo, so I'll just have to submit the query and results I get. Thank you again, sir!

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. It's a great site, but kind of flaky.